# Why am I getting an IOError when running this i2c example code on my Beaglebone Black?

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, i2c

Below is the image.py example in the [Adafruit SSD1306 Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306), for driving OLED display through i2c on a BeagleBone Black.  It is giving me an IOError, but I am confused as to what it means.  Is the IOError likely a problem with the code itself, or an i2c configuration issue on the BeagleBone?

```
import time

import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_SSD1306

import Image

# Beaglebone Black pin configuration:
RST = 'P9_12'
# Note the following are only used with SPI:
DC = 'P9_15'
SPI_PORT = 1
SPI_DEVICE = 0

# 128x32 display with hardware I2C:
#disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST)

# 128x64 display with hardware I2C:
disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST)

# 128x32 display with hardware SPI:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=RST, dc=DC, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=8000000))

# 128x64 display with hardware SPI:
# disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST, dc=DC, spi=SPI.SpiDev(SPI_PORT, SPI_DEVICE, max_speed_hz=8000000))

# Initialize library.
disp.begin()

# Clear display.
disp.clear()
disp.display()

# Load image based on OLED display height.  Note that image is converted to 1 bit color.
if disp.height == 64:
        image = Image.open('happycat_oled_64.ppm').convert('1')
else:
        image = Image.open('happycat_oled_32.ppm').convert('1')

# Alternatively load a different format image, resize it, and convert to 1 bit color.
#image = Image.open('happycat.png').resize((disp.width, disp.height), Image.ANTIALIAS).convert('1')

# Display image.
disp.image(image)
disp.display()
```

Please see the trace below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-3.5.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/ubuntu/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 47, in <module>
    disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_64(rst=RST)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_SSD1306/SSD1306.py", line 239, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_SSD1306/SSD1306.py", line 105, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 64, in get_i2c_device
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 75, in __init__
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

`Image = Image.open('happycat_oled_64.ppm','r').convert('1')`

OR

`Image = Image.open('happycat_oled_64.ppm','w').convert('1')`